# How to set default PropertyDescriptor to a property?

Tags: c#, .net, propertydescriptor

Are there an attribute for setting default PropertyDescriptor for a property? I just want to add a attribute to a property and specify PropertyDescriptor. And then the instance of the PropertyDescriptor would have been created. 
I haven't found the attribute in .net framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.  However, you could implement [`ICustomTypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) or (easier) inherit from  [`CustomTypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor.aspx).

If your objects are contained in a collection, you could make the collection implement [`ITypedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.aspx) instead.